# jQuery inside Media Wiki pages (not just in the Monobook.js or extensions)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mediawiki

I'm trying to do some simple jQuery stuff 'dynamically' from within a MediaWiki content page. Its really just to 'beauty up' some different features.

I've done the following:
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/JQuery
[http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgRawHtml](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgRawHtml) (mainly for Paypal buttons initially)

The below code does not work. This is put in a blank content page.

```
<html>
<script>
$j(document).ready(function(){
    $j('#test').hover(
        function(){
            $j('#test').attr('background-color','red');
        }, 
        function(){ 
            $j('#test').removeAttr('background-color');
        }
    );
});
</script>
<div id="test">Howdy</div>
</html>
```

Nothing happens...

Any ideas?

**Update:**

I have attempted this simple solution with no result.

example.com/wiki/index.php?title=MediaWiki:Common.js

```
$j('#jTest-Howdy').hover(
        function(){
            $j('#jTest-Howdy').addClass('jTest-red');
        }, 
        function(){ 
            $j('#jTest-Howdy').removeClass('jTest-red');
        }
);
```

example.com/wiki/index.php?title=MediaWiki:Common.css

```
.jTest-red { background-color: red; }
```

example.com/wiki/index.php?title=jQueryTest

```
<html>
<div id="jTest-Howdy">Howdy</div>
</html>
```

as you can see here, this code should work IF jQuery was being loaded properly...
http://jsfiddle.net/5qFhv/

but it is not working for me... any help?

Comment: Do you need to use jQuery?  I'm wondering if you could accomplish the same thing with some css?  Or are you wanting to do more complicated stuff than what your code above shows?

Comment: @wilbbe01: I'm definitely wanting to do more complicated things than what is above... Above is just a simple example that shows that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about MediaWiki, but to me it looks like some simple javascript mistakes.

In the first sample you are trying to set an attribute on the element,
when you need to set the css or style attribute.

```
$j('#test').css('background-color', 'red');
```

In both samples you are binding an event to an element that doesn't exist yet in the DOM, so it will fail. You could use the live method, which will work for existing and future elements introduced in the DOM.

```
$j.('#test').live('mouseover', function(){
  $j(this).addClass('hover-class');
}).live('mouseout', function(){
  $j(this).removeClass('hover-class');
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for the tip about using the `.live` method.  I will attempt this soon.

Comment: .live fixed this issue. I am now able to 'dynamically' add javascript to my Common.js file, css styles to my Monobook.css and it will in fact properly modify the related stuff.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the jQuery that's loaded by MediaWiki 1.17, be aware that most JavaScript is loaded *after* page content. An inline <script> element is executed immediately when it's reached, so $j would not be defined at this time -- you'll probably see some errors in your JavaScript error console to this effect.

(Offhand I'm not sure about the jQuery that's included with 1.16; versions of MediaWiki prior to that as far as I know did not include jQuery.)

Generally what you want to do here is to either put JavaScript code modules into the 'MediaWiki:Common.js' page and let that hook up to your HTML markup, or create a MediaWiki extension -- which you can then invoke from your pages, and which will let you create any fun HTML and JavaScript output you like.

- http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interface/JavaScript
- http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Developing_extensions

Code you put in your 'MediaWiki:Common.js' page will be loaded after other UI initialization, ensuring that code and variables are present so you can call into jQuery etc.

Comment: If I add the normal "<script src= />" tags to the monobook js,  should it define the $j (assuming it is the one included with media wiki and not the normal one)?

Comment: adding the script tags to the common.js did not work. I guess I'm going to have to create some 'class specific' things to do what I'm looking for. Not really what I wanted to do... unless someone else has a solution soon...

Comment: For the common.js page, you'll want to put the JS in directly, not inside a script tag. You should definitely check your browser's JavaScript error console to confirm whether your code is actually being loaded and how it's erroring out...

Comment: check the update. I have tried your solution (of adding it to the Common.js) but it does not work for me...

Answer (score 1):

Try putting all your custom jQuery code in its own file, then load it as a module with ResourceLoader, after jQuery.

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader/Migration_guide_for_extension_developers

Also, as a debugging method: completely load your site in Firefox, then enter your custom jQuery code in the console. If it works, your problem is a race condition. If it doesn't, jQuery isn't loading for some reason.

Comment: Extensions are one of the things that I'm trying to stay away from (as stated in my question above). The tip about checking about a race condition or if jQuery is loading is a good and I will have to check it out. Thanks!

Comment: @g19fanatic: FYI ResourceLoader is not an extension. It is how MW is loading jQuery and all the other scripts it comes with out-of-the-box.